# RestKit: connect relationships with routing

Tags: ios, restkit, restkit-0.20

I have a CoreData relationship between a Car and a CarSetting. CarSetting can store different types of settings for a new car like rims, painting, transmission and so on. The Car has a relationship "carsettings" and the CarSetting has a relationship "cars". The CarSetting can load all "cars" from an API which have these settings. Cars do not have a reference to all the available CarSettings (obviously). With RestKit is it possible to set the relationship "cars" from CarSetting when i call `getObjectsAtPathForRelationship:` or how can I tell RestKit to set all retrieved Objects from the carMapping to the CarSetting "cars" relationship?

Any help appreciated ;)

RestKit 0.20.x

Comment: You already have the cars? And the server response holds the nested cars or at least their unique ids?

Comment: At the time the cars are loaded from the API I have a carsetting. I only want to connect the relationship from the cars and the carsetting after or during the cars get loaded. The cars have a unique id. I can only load cars from the server with a specified carsetting.

Comment: So the car setting I'd is part of the URL you load to get the cars?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The cars get loaded with the help of parameters in the url like ?color=red&transmission=manual&brand=audi. So there is really no connection between these two types.

Comment: I thought that if I set up a routing and then use RestKit to give me an url for a relationship RestKit automatically connects the loaded Objects with the relationship. This is sadly not the case :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with the help of the RKMappingResult where I can iterate through every mapped Car entity and assign the CarSetting to the carsettings property of the Car. After that I saved everything back to CoreData.